# How to solve "customFds not yet supported" Error

Tags: node.js, jake, geddy

I installed geddy.js. After installation i created and app with geddy using command:

```
geddy app myapp
cd myapp
```

But when i tried geddy inside myapp i am getting following error with log details as:

```
Error: customFds not yet supported
    at setStreamOption (child_process_uv.js:386:13)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process_uv.js:397:3)
    at Object.spawn (child_process_uv.js:317:9)
    at Object.createWorker (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/hack_master.js:46:22)
    at Object.createWorkers (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:291:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:207:14)
    at [object Object].runItem (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/utils/async.js:108:10)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/utils/async.js:113:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/lib/utils/async.js:148:54)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:195:26)
```

Can anyone help me resolving the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of node are you on? You can run `node --version` to find this.

Comment: Also, you may want to comment on https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/113 with your OS and node version, because apparently someone else is having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem because I was using an old version of node. Try to upgrade